# How to fix my code to be able to create new repositories

Tags: python, bitbucket-cloud

I can't create new repositoies in bitbucket cloud with code below.

I'm able to delete repositiries (with change form 'post' to 'delete' requests method). When I'm using code below I've got http 400 which means according to api docs - If the input document was invalid, or if the caller lacks the privilege to create repositories under the targeted account.

```py
import requests

username = 'user@mail.com'
password = 'password'


headers = {"Content-Type": 'application/json'}
auth = (username, password)
bb_base_url = f"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/reponame"

res = requests.post(bb_base_url, headers=headers, auth=auth)

print(res)
```

So would like to ask for help to refactor code in way I will be able to do two things

Comment: 400 means bad request, check your json before posting

Comment: Are you using reponame or repo_slug?

Comment: @ Ruturaj I'm green so I hardly know what to change in json... would not ask if knew

Comment: @Piotr - yes I'm using repo name, for example 'test'

Comment: According to REST API documentation you should use repo_slug there

Comment: I'm using word 'test' so no brainer for slug here... it will be the same. One of the anwsers from Atlassian forums by Atalssian team member:
You can find the repo-slug in the URL for your repository. 

For example in one of my test repositories, documentation-tests, the URL is:

https://bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/documentation-tests 

Teamsinspace is the owner, and documentation-tests is the repo slug.

There is definetly something worng with Jason as Ruturaj mentioned but have no idea what...

Comment: have you [authenticated](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication) before?

Comment: If the same code allow me to delete repo I dont think (of course maybe I'm wrong) extra auth is needed...

Comment: maybe that's a bug… I remember when I sent some rest request to bitbucket that I used this authentication. Worth a try?

Comment: Sure why not :)

Comment: So the bug was simple - in requests syntaxt, was missing json part